# A simple inequality estimation

Tags: inequality

I come across an estimation that seems simple but......

Let $1<\beta_1<\beta_0<2$ and $\beta_1\,,\beta_0$ satisfy the following three conditions:

1. $\beta_0^2(\beta_1-1)\geq\beta_1$,
2. $\beta_1^2(\beta_0-1)\geq\beta_0$
3. $\beta_0\beta_1-\beta_1>1$

then prove that

$\beta_0\beta_1(\beta_0+\beta_1-\beta_0\beta_1)\leq 1+\beta_0(\beta_1-1)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since:
$$\beta_0\beta_1(\beta_0+\beta_1-\beta_0\beta_1)=\beta_0\beta_1(1-(\beta_0-1)(\beta_1-1))$$
and:
$$1+\beta_0(\beta_1-1) = (1-\beta_0)+\beta_0\beta_1,$$
you have to prove:
$$-\beta_0\beta_1(\beta_0-1)(\beta_1-1)\leq (1-\beta_0).$$
Since $\beta_0>1$, we can divide both sides by $(\beta_0-1)$, then prove:
$$\beta_0\beta_1(\beta_1-1)\geq 1.$$
Notice that the inequality number 2 gives:
$$\beta_1^2\geq\frac{\beta_0}{\beta_0-1}\geq 2, $$
so $\beta_1\geq\sqrt{2}$. Notice that the inequality number 3 gives $\beta_0\beta_1\geq(1+\beta_1)$, so:
$$\beta_0\beta_1(\beta_1-1)\geq\beta_1^2-1\geq 2-1=1,$$
QED.

Comment: Moreover, by inserting the bound for $\beta_1$ in the first inequality, you get $\beta_0\geq\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}$, so the third inequality can be strengthened, too.

Comment: the lower bound of $\beta_0$ is golden mean

Comment: Yes, I was wrong in the previous comment. Anyway, I would like to notice that inequality 3. follows from inequality 2. and $\beta_0>\beta_1$, so it is redundant. From $$\beta_0^2\geq 1+\frac{1}{\beta_1-1}\geq 1+\frac{1}{\beta_0-1}$$ $\beta_0\geq\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ follows, so $$\beta_0\beta_1(\beta_1-1)\geq\frac{\beta_1^3}{1+\beta_1}\geq 4-2\sqrt{2},$$ holds, since 2. implies $\beta_0\geq\frac{\beta_1^2}{\beta_1^2-1}$. Moreover, the stronger $$\beta_0\beta_1(\beta_0+\beta_1-\beta_0\beta_1)\leq C\left((1-\beta_0)+\beta_0\beta_1\right)$$ holds with $C=\frac{4}{7}\left(3-\sqrt{2}\right).$